# Change icon based on posts from another page

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, notifications

Apologies if this has been asked before. I searched and couldn't find anything.

I have a basic landing page website that has an icon that links to "Hot Alerts", ie notifications of system outages. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to either change the icon or add a notification bubble (similar to Facebook notifications) if content on a Sharepoint blog has been updated in the past "X" hours.

Here's the icon I'm referring to:
[Hot Alerts Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri332.png)

I've found examples of how to style the icon with CSS, but those all require manually entering the number of new notifications.

What I need is a way for the icon to "check" the sharepoint page for its most recent post when the landing page is loaded.

Most of my colleagues use Internet Explorer, but Chrome is creeping into the workflow.

Comment: I think you need to resort to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use it the Javascript Object Model (JSOM). You will be able to read lists (for new posts) upon page loading and then showing or hiding the icon. A lot of example code to read lists can be found on SO.

If you want to use a 'bubble', take a look at sp.ui.notify (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee550701%28v=office.14%29.aspx) methods to show an overlay notification popup on the page.

Comment: plus: Jquery instead of plain javascript can facilitate your coding ;-)

Comment: Thanks Verthosa! I think that might be a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely this can be done with pure CSS. Any of the following languages will provide suitable solutions: JQuery, JS, PHP.

In PHP, you could use `$_GET` to place the variable in the URL. So one page would use `$_GET` to post the variable to the URL and the PHP file loading the page would use it to retrieve the variable from the URL.

Comment: Thank's CSS Fan! I don't know who voted you down, but I appreciate you giving me a few languages to look into. I think JQuery might be the way to go.